# Show that an inequality is true using mathematical induction and the mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, induction

A question in my math book is: "Use mathematical induction to show that:

$$e^x>1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

if $x>0$ and $n$ is any positive integer."

Apparently the solution involves applying the Mean Value Theorem on:

$$g(t)=e^t-1-t-\frac{t^2}{2!}-...-\frac{t^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$

Then:

$$\frac{g(x)}{x}=\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}=g'(c)$$

Then it states that $g'(c)$ is positive.

QUESTION 1: why is $g'(c)$ positive?

QUESTION 2: how would one answer (in small understandable steps) the original question of my math book? I don't fully understand the method used.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the Taylor Series expansion for the exponential function? I think you will see readily the idea behind the inequality if you know its Taylor series.

Comment: $g'(c)$ is positive because of the induction hypothesis.

Comment: @William I've heard of it, but not really worked with it yet. I guess at this point the math book doesn't assume I know it yet.

Comment: Just look at it -- you don't have to understand it fully to get the idea behind this problem, but it will be a lot clearer to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P_n(x)=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+...+\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$.

*Initialisation:

$\mathrm e^x >1$ is true for x >0, since  the exponential function is increasing and $\mathrm e^0=1$.

*Induction step:*

We'll use this corollary of the *Mean value theorem*:

> Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions on an interval $I$, differentiable in the interior of $I$, and $x_0\in I$. Suppose $f(x_0)\ge g(x_0)\;$ and $\;f'(x)>g'(x)$ for all $x>x_0\;$ in $I$.
>
> Then $\;f(x)> g(x)$ for all $x>x_0\;$ (in $I$).

Now suppose $\mathrm e^x>P_n(x)$ for all $x>0$, and observe $(\mathrm e^x)'=\mathrm e^x$, $\, (P_{n+1}(x))'=P_n(x)$. So you just have to apply the corollary.

Comment: Great, I never noticed $P_n = (P_{n+1})'$. Can you use only this  to show that $P_n \to \exp$ ?

Comment: Yes, but actually , $\exp=\lim_{n\to\infty}P_n$ is the definition of the exponential function.

Comment: Of course I know. I meant from the $e^{\ln x} = x, \ \ \ln x = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$ definition. $\ \ \ $  On any compact : $\frac{P_n(x)}{ P_{n+1}(x)} \to 1$ uniformly, hence $\frac{{P_n}'(x)}{P_n(x)}  \to 1$ uniformly, so that $\ln(P_n(x))= C+ \int_0^x \frac{{P_n}'(t)}{P_n(t)} dt \to x + C$ uniformly, hence $P_n(x) \to e^{C} e^{x}$ uniformly, and $C = 0$ since $P_n(0) = 1$.  (exactly in the same way you can prove also that $f_n(x) = (1+x/n)^{1/n} \to e^x$ )

Answer (score 1):

Claim $(n)$:

> $$\qquad\forall x>0,\qquad e^{x} > \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Case $n=0$: trivial. Induction step: given Claim $(n)$, it follows that:

$$ e^{x} = 1+\int_{0}^{x}e^{z}\,dz > 1+\int_{0}^{x}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{z^{n}}{n!}\,dz = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{x^k}{k!}.$$